# How do I handle RabbitMQ Consumer Cancellation Notification when using Spring ChannelAwareMessageListener

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

Newbie to RabbitMQ and new to Java.

I'm attempting to write a listener that will use manual acks and handle consumer cancellation notifications using the java Spring AMQP abstraction. Can I accomplish both tasks by using the Spring abstraction?

I want to write a listener that will pull messages from a queue and process that message (maybe write to a database or something). I planned on using manual acknowledgements so that if processing of the message fails or can't be completed for some reason, I can reject and requeue. So far I think I've found that in order to manually ack/nack/reject using Spring AMQP I have to use a `ChannelAwareMessageListener`.

I realize that I should be handling Consumer Cancellation Notifications from RabbitMQ, however using the `ChannelAwareMessageListener` I don't really see a way to code for this. The only way I see to handle CCN is to write code using the lower level java client api by calling `channel.basicConsume()` and passing a new `DefaultConsumer` instance which allows you to handle message delivery and cancels.

I also don't see how I would set the `clientProperties` on the `ConnectionFactory` (to tell the broker I can handle the CCN) since I am getting the factory from a bean in config.

My pseudo code of the listener and creation of container is below.

```
public class MyChannelAwareListener implements ChannelAwareMessageListener
{
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception
    {
        msgProcessed = processMessage(message);

        if(msgProcessed)    
           channel.basicAck(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false);
        else
           channel.basicReject(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), true);  
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext   (MY_CONTEXT_PATH);
    rabbitConnectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)ctx.getBean("rabbitConnectionFactory");

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();

    MyChannelAwareListener listener = new MyChannelAwareListener();
    container.setMessageListener(listener);
    container.setQueueNames("myQueue");
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    container.start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For setting the client properties you need to use the `setClientProperties` method in the `ConnectionFactory` (assuming this ConnectionFactory is the object from the RabbitMQ Java library). This method is expecting a `Map<String, Object>` which contains the properties of the client and the capabilities. The following lines are the default values inside the RabbitMQ Java library:

```
Map<String,Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put("product", LongStringHelper.asLongString("RabbitMQ"));
props.put("version", LongStringHelper.asLongString(ClientVersion.VERSION));
props.put("platform", LongStringHelper.asLongString("Java"));
props.put("copyright", LongStringHelper.asLongString(Copyright.COPYRIGHT));
props.put("information", LongStringHelper.asLongString(Copyright.LICENSE));

Map<String, Object> capabilities = new HashMap<String, Object>();
capabilities.put("publisher_confirms", true);
capabilities.put("exchange_exchange_bindings", true);
capabilities.put("basic.nack", true);
capabilities.put("consumer_cancel_notify", true);

props.put("capabilities", capabilities);
```

For managing ACKs and Consumer cancelling I am not sure how to do it with the Spring AMQP abstraction, however it is perfectly doable with `channel.basicConsume` which gives you the possibility to handle all the scenarios through all the callback methods:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.1.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.1.5/

Hope this helps!